# Strategies for avoiding merge conflicts, e.g. in git

Tags: version-control, merge-conflict-resolution

Files that one appends or prepends to regularly have a tendency towards merge conflicts.

E.g. we have a `ChangeLog.txt` file at the toplevel of our repository. Whenever somebody makes a substantial change, a customer-friendly description of the change gets prepended to `ChangeLog.txt`. This causes frequent merge conflicts as different developers merge separate changes or as single developers rebase and change the sequence of commits and thereby `ChangeLog.txt` change order.

(We also have a `UpgradeDatabaseSchema.pm` perl library that likewise has N entries pr. version that also tends to have merge conflicts, but lets stick with `ChangeLog.txt`).

How does one nicely avoid such merge conflicts?

The only thing I've come up with is a directory structure, where instead of committing `ChangeLog.txt`, we commit entries to a `changeLog` directory in separate files:

```
changeLog/
    v1.1/
        fooFeature.txt
        bug-4524-fix.txt
        refactoredWhatever.txt
    v1.2/
        bug-4522-fix.txt
        barFeature.txt
        removedFoobar.txt
```

And then let `ChangeLog.txt` be built from e.g. concatenating these files in some way (and not tracking/committing `ChangeLog.txt` in git). This is a little cumbersome...

We also briefly considered just using `git log` instead of a `ChangeLog.txt`, but won't because the audience is different: git log is for developers, and `ChangeLog.txt` is for customers. Also, one can't easily change the description of a commit in `git log` without altering git history and breaking branching for everybody.

So:

- Live with the merge conflicts
- Use a directory structure instead of a single flat file
- Use git log

Are there other ways to do it that we've overlooked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the "union" merge strategy for single files as explained here: http://krlmlr.github.io/using-gitattributes-to-avoid-merge-conflicts/

Just add a line to .gitattributes

```
ChangeLog.txt merge=union
```